# Is it possible to create sp with an integer array parameter in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I want to call a stored procedure from a Web Api controller. As a parameter i need to pass id's of items to the sp but id count is not stable. For a case i may pass 3 ids for another it may be 10 ids. Is it possible to pass an array or list of numbers to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15), [JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), or [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15).